# How to make enter the submit button in a form

Tags: html, forms, http-post

I have a form for logging into my website. I need to make it so that when the user hits enter, the form submits. How can I do this? Please provide code.

```
<form id="login" action="myHome.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add an `<input type="submit">` and hide it with CSS so that the browser knows what to trigger when enter is pressed, yet still not show a button. For the sake of accessibility and ease of use, I'd show the button even if not that many people use it (enter is much nicer).

Comment: For me this only worked when the cursor was in one of the `text` fields, not if tabbing to the hidden `submit` button. The jQuery solution worked for me.

Comment: You can also do <button type="submit">Submit</button>, if you're targeting HTML5 compliant browsers.

Answer (score 6):

add a handler to on keydown and check for keycode == 13. Make this submit the form like below

```
function addInputSubmitEvent(form, input) {
    input.onkeydown = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            form.submit();
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: would it be better for it to be handled naturally by the form submission mechanism instead of short-circuiting it by using the keycode 13 detection to do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

This should happen by default.  In my experience some browsers require an `<input type=submit>` field, but generally this is not a requirement.