# HTML / ERB - Standard-Button?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

In the picture you can see 2Buttons: [screenshot](http://www.bildercache.de/anzeige.html?dateiname=20140405-173000-578.png)

I want the user to just type in the email and password and accept it by pressing return.

Is there an opportunity to set this up?

I know that there is a option in C#, but I forgot how it's called. (Standard-Button?)

There are 2 input-texts and 2buttons (Login-Form / Register)
eMail - Password - Login-Btn and or-Register-btn.
The user types in his email and password. After that he press "return" to accept and he is logged in.
How is the options called that the login-btn is the ... first button to choose by pressing "return"?***

That's what I am using:

- Ruby on Rails 4
- HTML
- HTML.ERB
- Bootstrap 3

Comment: Like this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210678/how-to-make-enter-the-submit-button-in-a-form?rq=1

Comment: OMG.. :D Thank you.
I took a example from Bootstrap3 and the button-tag was <button>...
I just changed it now to <input type="submit" value="login/anmelden"/> and it works. Thanks..

Comment: @TylerH please remove duplicate tag. There is a really good answer written by Richard Peck. Thanks

Comment: Closing the question as a duplicate does not remove or reduce the usefulness of any existing answers here. You yourself said the duplicate target answered your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have an answer, but to help you understand it, you need to remember Rails renders everything as HTML on the browser-side; so every element you want to display has to be some sort of HTML object

If you want to show a button in Rails, there are a number of ways to do it:

---

**[`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to)**

This creates a simple form which points to a URL. The form has a `button` element inside, making it look like a pure HTML button to the user:

```
<%= button_to "New", action: "new" %>
# => "<form method="post" action="/controller/new" class="button_to">
#      <div><input value="New" type="submit" /></div>
#    </form>"
```

---

**[`f.submit`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-submit)**

For your specific issue, I think you'll benefit from `f.submit`, which basically adds a submit button to your form:

```
<%= form_for @var do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit "Register" %>
<% end %>
```

If you'd like to style this, you'll be able to apply classes to the button directly:

```
<%= f.submit "Text", class: "class" %>
```

Comment: That's nice of you :) I just wanted to get the front-end works at first, but I know that need a button_to or f.submit (that I didnt know). So thanks for the example code of f.submit.